# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application Multi dex Application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am facing Strange issue in my android application. Its always give me error called

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   io.hitanime.app.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find
>   class "io.hitanime.app.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/base.apk", zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /data/app/io.hitanime.app-957U27HR57arXVvYGSCFSQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]

I have multidex enabled in my application and trying to solve it from last two days but unable to solve it.

I have tried 
1) Clean Project and Rebuild
2) Invalidate cache and Restart
3) Disable Multidex

Let me know if someone can help me for solve the puzzle. 
Thanks

Comment: Disable Instant Run(Android Studio->Preferences->Instant Run, uncheck "Enable Instance Run" and after that try to clean and rebuild project @Raju Bhatt

Comment: Its not working. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but anyone faced with this problem again try adding below lines to your app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```